# Azure Migrate: Tools to analyze the application and report - Technology stack, version, external dependencies like database, kafka?

Tags: azure

We plan to migrate or modernize all of our applications to Azure and looking a tool to discovery & assess the applications and report the following

> Technology stack, version, external dependencies like database, kafka & etc and Server details like OS version, CPU, Memory & Disk.

I did go through

1. Azure App Service Migration Assistant
2. Azure Migrate

for "Discovery & Assessment".

I don't find these report contains the required information. Is there a single tool that analyzes provides all of the required information like cloudamize, movere & etc?

Answer (score 2):

In single tool that analyzes provides all of the required information you can make use ***AHEAD Software***

These tools have been designed specifically for application migration and can offer a detailed report on the technology stack, version, external dependencies, and server information like the OS version, CPU, memory, and storage. They can also provide you with information on guiding principles and assist in the planning and execution of the migration process.

[image]

- Note that: Azuer is not re if you use any third-party tools, make sure to register with those third-party services, integrate them into the Azure Migrate interface, and then have a consistent experience with a variety of tools.

***Reference***:

[Azure Migrate: A Suite Ride to the Cloud](https://www.ahead.com/resources/azure-migrate-a-suite-ride-to-the-cloud)

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with the resources to get to know the features of AHEAD Software with respect to Application Assessment for Cloud migration?